# Input switching in C

Tags: c, function, if-statement, input, scanf

I am trying to create a basic paint program in C and I need to input the figure first then the coordinates for the said figures. I have to input first the figure then the coordinates but in order to input the specific coordinates for a specific image to be passed on to a function, I have to make a conditional statement. My code goes like this

```
fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
      if("\n"==input[strlen(input)-1]) // to remove '\n' from string
          input[strlen(input)-1]=='\0';
      if(strcmp(input,point)==0){
         scanf("%d %d",&x1,&y1);
         point(x1,y1); 
      }
      if(strcmp(input,rectangle)==0){
         scanf("%d %d",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
         rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2) // x1,y1 for top left coordinate x2,y2 for bottom right
      }
```

If I run the code and enter:

```
point // enter
12 13
```

it works, but I have to run it like so:

```
point 12 13 // only one space in between those three inputs
```

I can't seem to run it that way. The input image should be in the same line as the input coordinate. I tried using `scanf()` then `if{ scanf() }` but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `char figure[1024] = {0}; 
       int x, y; 
       scanf("%s%d%d", figure, &x, &y);`

Comment: I posted this as answer but then deleted since looks like you require the value of figure to dictate the number of inputs (coordinates). Not possible I believe.

Answer (score 1):

you can't compare strings with == you have to use

```
strcmp(char *string1,char*string2)
```

you can do like that :

```
char input[20];
int resul[4];
scanf("%s%d%d",input,&resul[0],&resul[1]);
if (input[0]=='r') scanf("%d%d",&resul[2],&resul[3]);
```

Comment: I edited it to strcmp but I still can't figure out how to input with the format of <figure> <coordinates of figure> and not <figure> '\n' <coordinates of figure>

Answer (score 1):

The code analyzed starts with:

```
fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
if("\n"==input[strlen(input)-1]) // to remove '\n' from string
    input[strlen(input)-1]=='\0';
```

You should check the return value from `fgets()` so you know whether there is any data in `input` to analyze.

The `if` should be `if (input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n')`, testing against the character `'\n'` and not the string `"\n"`<sup>*</sup>.  You should have been getting compiler warnings about a type mismatch.  If you weren't getting such warnings, get a better compiler.  If you were getting the warnings, pay heed to your compiler; it knows more about C than you do (and doesn't generate warnings just for the fun of doing so).

The assignment after the `if` needs a single `=` not a double `==` — you should probably have been getting a warning about a statement that does nothing.

<sup>* I recognize that some people recommend the order `if ('\n' == input[strlen(input)-1])` but it doesn't read as well to me. The mechanism is intended to protect against the `==` vs `=` mistake in a condition.  It is imperfect — it can't protect you when both the LHS and RHS are variables (`if (lhs = rhs)`), for example — and a decent compiler will warn you if you have an assignment masquerading as a conditional (just as it will warn you about a conditional masquerading as an assignment).</sup>

The code should start off like this, therefore:

```
if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != 0)
{
    if (input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n')
        input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
```

I'm ignoring the 'inefficiency' of the repeated call to `strlen()`; there are bigger problems to worry about.  Note that the revised code check the result of the input operation; you run into trouble if `fgets()` detects EOF or an error and you have not tested the result of `fgets()`.

The original version of the code then continued with:

```
if(input == "point"){
   scanf("%d %d",&x1,&y1);
   point(x1,y1); 
}
if(input == "rectangle"){
   scanf("%d %d",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
   rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2) // x1,y1 for top left coordinate x2,y2 for bottom right
}
```

As was correctly pointed out by [jambono](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2685354/jambono) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18575010/15168), this does not work; you can't compare strings like that.

Unfortunately, the rewrite was:

```
if(strcmp(input,point)==0){
   scanf("%d %d",&x1,&y1);
   point(x1,y1); 
}
if(strcmp(input,rectangle)==0){
   scanf("%d %d",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
   rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2) // x1,y1 for top left coordinate x2,y2 for bottom right
}
```

This too should have generated warnings from the compiler, because the strings were changed to function pointers — the compiler should have been complaining about converting function pointers to `const char *` or thereabouts.

The correct comparisons could be:

```
if (strcmp(input, "point") == 0)
if (strcmp(input, "rectangle") == 0)
```

These would work as long as the word appeared on a line on its own, with the data following on a separate line:

```
point
1 2
rectangle
2 3 4 5
```

---

#### Answer before question was formatted for readability

Of course, the second `scanf()` needs the format string fixing, and you should always test that `scanf()` worked as intended:

```
if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2) != 4)
    ...deal with error...
```

Note that the `scanf()` call will leave the newline behind, ready to be read by another call to `fgets()` as the only character (that's left) on the line.  I think you might do better with a second call to `fgets()` to read the line with the data and then use `sscanf()` to parse that line.

Assembling all the changes (using `scanf()`):

```
if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != 0)
{
    if (input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n')
        input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
    if (strcmp(input, "point") == 0)
    {
        if (scanf("%d %d",&x1,&y1) != 2)
            ...report format error and return/exit...
        point(x1, y1); 
    }
    else if (strcmp(input, "rectangle") == 0)
    {
        if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2) != 4)
            ...report format error and return/exit...
        rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    else
        ...unexpected input (format error)...
}
```

Using `fgets()` and `sscanf()`:

```
if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != 0)
{
    if (input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n')
        input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
    if (strcmp(input, "point") == 0)
    {
        if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == 0)
            ...report unexpected EOF and return/exit...
        if (sscanf(input, "%d %d",&x1,&y1) != 2)
            ...report format error and return/exit...
        point(x1, y1); 
    }
    else if (strcmp(input, "rectangle") == 0)
    {
        if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == 0)
            ...report unexpected EOF and return/exit...
        if (sscanf(input, "%d %d %d %d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2) != 4)
            ...report format error and return/exit...
        rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Note that in the example using `fgets()`, you have the entire line of input that you can report to the user, which is probably easier for them to find than finding what's left after `scanf()` has read some the line and refused to convert the rest.  For example, if the input was:

```
rectangle
10 10 2O 22
```

The conversion would fail on the `O` (should be a `0`), but the only information you'd be able to glean from the input for reporting to the user would be `O 22`, which is probably not as helpful as being able to show the whole line.

#### Answer after question was formatted for readability

The inputs are single lines:

```
point 1 1
rectangle 1 0 0 1
```

In that case, you can't use `scanf()` to get the numbers (because `fgets()` already read the whole line), so you will need to use `sscanf()` and won't need a second call to `fgets()`.  You do, however, have to modify the comparison code, and the calls to `sscanf()`.  I'd create a minuscule function to check whether a given string is a prefix of the other:

```
int str_prefix(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    return strncmp(haystack, needle, strlen(needle)) == 0;
}
```

This returns true if the `needle` can be found at the start of the `haystack`.  If you have a C99 or later compiler, you could qualify that with `static inline` (and could sensibly change the return type to `bool` or `_Bool`).

```
if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != 0)
{
    if (input[strlen(input)-1] == '\n')
        input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
    if (str_prefix(input, "point "))
    {
        if (sscanf(input, "point %d %d",&x1,&y1) != 2)
            ...report format error and return/exit...
        point(x1, y1); 
    }
    else if (str_prefix(input, "rectangle "))
    {
        if (sscanf(input, "rectangle %d %d %d %d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2) != 4)
            ...report format error and return/exit...
        rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Note the trailing blanks on the 'needle' strings.  This prevents you misinterpreting "pointed remark" as being the start of a 'point' line.

Instead of starting the format strings with the keyword, you could instead start the `sscanf()` search after the keyword:

```
if (sscanf(&input[sizeof("rectangle")], "%d %d %d %d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2) != 4)
```